# New Life - Latin translation

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary

I’m looking for farm name ideas and am stuck on the concept of it being a “new life”... celebrating a changing of life’s season, etc. All I can find really is the general translation, I’m not sure how correct it is. So, looking for help! Is it just vita nova?

Answer (score 4):

"New life" is **vita nova**.

Comment: And *Vita Nova* is also the famous Latin title of a famously not-Latin work by Dante. **Incipit vita nova** - A new life begins (when Dante meets his Beatrice).

Answer (score 3):

It's *vita nova* or *nova vita*. The word order is relatively free, but it also has preferences. I'm not quite sure what it would be in focus-comment structure.

*Villa Nova* as a known place name implies not necessarily that there was an old village somewhere else, just that there's something new in the place, where there wasn't a village before. Whereas *Nova Scotia* implies that there was an old Scotia somewhere else.

I'm only guessing from examples, while my recently acquired understanding of Greek phrase structure ([lecture](https://spw.uni-goettingen.de/aig/mp4/GRC-STR-005.mp4)) is barely relevant, nor way up there. But the examples check out I believe.